# WPF Combobox editor style binding is not working

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, infragistics

I have the following xaml code.

I am trying to bind custom class `UnitCategory` to combo box.

But seems to be there is an issue in code.

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:ComboSourceConverter x:Key="cscconv" />

        <Style x:Key="UnitCategoryStyle" TargetType="{x:Type igEditors:XamComboEditor}">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.UnitCategories, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
            <Setter Property="SelectedItem" Value ="{Binding Path=DataItem.UnitCategory}" />
            <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="Name" />
        </Style>
        
        <Style x:Key="UnitStyle" TargetType="{x:Type igEditors:XamComboEditor }">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=DataItem.UnitCategory, Converter={StaticResource cscconv}}" />
        </Style>

    </Grid.Resources>
    <igWPF:XamDataGrid DataSource="{Binding data}" CellChanged="XamDataGrid_CellChanged">
        <igWPF:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
            <igWPF:FieldLayoutSettings AutoGenerateFields="False" />
        </igWPF:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
        <igWPF:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
            <igWPF:FieldLayout>
                <igWPF:FieldLayout.Fields>
                    <igWPF:Field Name="Item"></igWPF:Field>
                    <igWPF:Field Name="UnitCategory">
                        <igWPF:Field.Settings>
                            <igWPF:FieldSettings EditorStyle="{StaticResource UnitCategoryStyle}" />
                        </igWPF:Field.Settings>
                    </igWPF:Field>
                    <igWPF:Field Name="Unit">
                        <igWPF:Field.Settings>
                            <igWPF:FieldSettings EditorStyle="{StaticResource UnitStyle}" />
                        </igWPF:Field.Settings>
                    </igWPF:Field>
                </igWPF:FieldLayout.Fields>
            </igWPF:FieldLayout>
        </igWPF:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
    </igWPF:XamDataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Following view model. Here Unit category is not binding. Drop down in combo box is not showing. Is there any binding issue?

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<DataModel> data { get; set; }
    public List<UnitCategory> UnitCategories { get; set; }
    public static List<string> WeightUnits { get; set; }
    public static List<string> DistanceUnits { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        this.data = new ObservableCollection<DataModel>();

        this.UnitCategories = new List<UnitCategory>();

        UnitCategory u1 = new UnitCategory();
        u1.Name = "Wt";

        UnitCategory u2 = new UnitCategory();
        u2.Name = "Dt";


        this.UnitCategories.Add(u1);
        this.UnitCategories.Add(u2);



        WeightUnits = new List<string>()
        {
            "mg",
            "g",
            "kg"
        };

        DistanceUnits = new List<string>()
        {
            "cm",
            "m",
            "km"
        };

        DataModel data1 = new DataModel();
        data1.Item = "Item 1";
      
        DataModel data2 = new DataModel();
        data2.Item = "Item 2";
 
        this.data.Add(data1);
        this.data.Add(data2);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class DataModel 
{
    public string Item { get; set; }
    public UnitCategory UnitCategory { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }

    public DataModel()
    {
    }
}

public class UnitCategory
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Try change `AncestorType={x:Type Window}` to the `AncestorType={x:Type igWPF:XamDataGrid}`

Comment: It's not working. Actually we need to take the window datacontext. Because For window -> VIewMOdel is datacontext. for Xamdatagrid -> Model is data context. For combob box it should take from viewmodel which is windows datacontext

Comment: For `igWPF:XamDataGrid` the `DataContext` is/should be `ViewModel`, since you do bind `DataSource="{Binding data}"` or you did post wrong code.

Comment: for XamdataGrid DataSOurce is List of DataModel which is data. For window Datacontext is instance of viewModel

Comment: No, list of `DataModel` is not the `DataContext` of `igWPF:XamDataGrid`, but the `DataSource`.

Comment: Yes You are correct. Posted code is correct

Comment: I changed.to `AncestorType={x:Type igWPF:XamDataGrid}` But still not getting values on combo box

Comment: I don't know if it makes a difference, but for ComboBoxes I always use `SelectedValue = "{Binding MyProperty}"` and I set SelectedValuePath as well as DisplayMemberPath

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that `igWPF:Field` or some of it's parts is not in visual tree. Try to create a `ViewModel` as static resource and then do bind to `StaticResource`.

```
<Window ... DataContext="{DynamicResource vmod}>
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:ViewModel x:Key="vmod" x:Shared="true"></local:ViewModel>"
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="UnitCategoryStyle" TargetType="{x:Type igEditors:XamComboEditor}">
                <Setter Property="Tag" Value ="{StaticResource vmod}"
                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Tag.UnitCategories, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" />
                <Setter Property="SelectedItem" Value ="{Binding Path=DataItem.UnitCategory}" />
                <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="Name" />
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid>

  ...

</Window>
```

Don't forget to remove setting of `DataContext` where you did it before.

Comment: Unfortunately, It's not working @Rekshino. I am not getting where is the problem. Seems to be everything is correct.